# Zero cross control for inductive loads

Tags: motor, inductive, zero-crossing

Is zero cross control acceptable for small motors? I know it is bad to have voltage and current out of phase for inductive loads but wanted to know if it would not be harmful to small motors (< 500 W).

Comment: "I know it is bad to have voltage and current out of phase for inductive loads" - huh? You *can't not* have the voltage and current out of phase for an inductive load. If they're not out of phase, it's not inductive.

Comment: I was mistaken, so is the problem with zero crossing that it may cause them to be in phase?

Answer (score 1):

Ideal phase crossing for a switching application depends on the type of load.

A resistive load doesn't care: whenever it is switched on (or off), is simply when current flows.

For a thyristor switch, a resistive load turns off (or, has an opportunity to, depending on drive/input) at the zero crossing.  A zero-crossing switch is fine for a resistive load, and indeed gives the symmetrical case that turn-on and turn-off can occur at the same point.  It's often made slightly more nuanced, where switching occurs on rising edges only, i.e. full cycle / burst control.  Which is effective for slow loads like heaters, where the resulting overall zero DC balance helps out the power company.

Zero crossing also works well for capacitive loads, where the sudden change in voltage (dV/dt) of switching off-zero would draw large peak currents.

For pure inductive loads, turn-off naturally occurs at the peak, and for neutral flux balance, turn-on should occur at the peak.  (Which should be the same peaks again for DC balance, assuming a slow on/off modulated application.)

Motors however are neither resistive nor inductive, but somewhere inbetween.  An induction motor at light load is dominant inductive, and at full rated load, dominant resistive, but a fraction of each remains (that is, the impedance ranges from say 10 to 90% resistive, with approximately the same amount of inductive reactance present in all conditions).  The natural turn-off point will occur at some other phase angle, dependent on load.  But we cannot know that in general, so turn-on is more or less arbitrary.

There is still the zero-flux motivation for peak switching, which may reduce peak inrush current; but there is also the transformer action of the motor itself, inducing large currents in a (potentially) stationary rotor.

Instead, design the switch for expected peak inrush current -- whether it's due to asymmetrical magnetization, transient voltage or normal (LRA) startup -- and switch whenever, doesn't matter if zero-crossing or random-phase.

Answer (score 0):

An asynchronous machine —an induction motor— is a transformer with a weird rotating, shorted secondary. All the rules of the transformer apply.

And that means you want to turn on at maximum voltage, not on zero-cross. Because that way magnetization starts with a quarter-wave, and then counter-magnetization follows. And so on. If you started with zero voltage, you had doubled magnetization —voltage-time "eaten"— in the beginning.

That additional quarter-wave from voltage-zero to voltage-maximum evens out only after a few dozen full periods and leads to a current spike on turn-on, as the iron core of the machine is overexcited.

Comment: But turning on at maximum voltage wouldn't be guaranteed by a "random turn-on" device either, correct?

Comment: The three phases are different to each other by 120 degrees so if you activate all together when "red" is maximum, the other two won't be maximum so, what is the general rule in these circumstances on three phase machines? I genuinely don't know.

Comment: My question is more focused on a single phase application

Comment: @Anda aka: there is no "cancelling effect" in three phase transformers because in that part of the transformer all three fluxes would run through they cancel out at any time — so this part is simply left out. It's the same for the asynchronous machine. Those parts of the flux that cancel out mean you have iron in the machine you don't need. So the rule is the same for a three-phase machine — the overexcitation is there, but localized in three blobs around the circumference of the stator.